# How does php artisan run commands and work internally?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

What happens when a command via `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call()` is called? Is it the same as `php -q filename.php` or does it use the `exec` function?

I tried to look at the source code, but the artisan class turned out to be a facade and my editor can't find the file.
[image]

Comment: Just use xdebug and debug the code in runtime. It's not that hard to set it up.

Comment: see https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Console/Concerns/CallsCommands.php#L26 and https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Console/Concerns/CallsCommands.html#method_call

Comment: Check the `@see` reference above every Facade.